# Set Azure DevOps Build Number to Gitversion MajorMinorPatch number

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, semantic-versioning, azure-devops-extensions, gitversion

I am trying to set my build number for my Azure DevOps Pipeline to my MajorMinorPatch version from gitversion.  I have the following in my YAML for my pipeline:

```
- task: GitVersion@5
  inputs:
    preferBundledVersion: false
    updateAssemblyInfo: true
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $versionInfo = '$($GITVERSION_MAJORMINORPATCH)'
      Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version;]$versionInfo")
- script: echo %Action%%BuildVersion%
  displayName: 'Set build version'
  env:
    Action: '##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]'
    BuildVersion: '$env:Version'
```

The problem is that when I run my pipeline, I get a pipeline name like: 0.1.0-alpha.70

I am not sure why I get the -alpha.70.  I know what they mean, I think, but I don't expect to see them in my string for Version.  When I run gitversion locally, my MajorMinorPatch string is 0.1.0 and that is all I want to see.  Can anyone help me get just that information?

EDIT: For anyone that is curious, I am including my GitVersion.yml here, it is pretty much the standard config:

```
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
mode: ContinuousDeployment
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ''
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
branches:
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: alpha
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    regex: ^dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    source-branches: []
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 0
  master:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^master$
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
  release:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: beta
    increment: None
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^releases?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - master
    - support
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^features?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - master
    - release
    - feature
    - support
    - hotfix
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  pull-request:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: PullRequest
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)'
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^(pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - master
    - release
    - feature
    - support
    - hotfix
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  hotfix:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - master
    - support
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
    pre-release-weight: 30000
  support:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^support[/-]
    source-branches:
    - master
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
    pre-release-weight: 55000
ignore:
  sha: []
commit-date-format: yyyy-MM-dd
merge-message-formats: {}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hi @BigDevJames Did you tried below updated answer. It seems you need to use $(GitVersion.MajorMinorPatch) to reference to the gitversion. And used $(Version) to update the build number. Please let me know if there is any question.

Comment: I did try, and my build number still has the string on it.  I'm still hoping to figure out why.

Comment: For troubleshooting, Can you try adding write-host command to output values of those variables in your powershell and script task, just to check if the variables has be assigned the correct value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, what I was attempting to do really isn't the way to pass along the version number.  Instead, I am now using a transform to update the value in my JSON configuration and that is being published as the build artifact.  Here is my current iteration of my azure-pipelines.yml:

```
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)-$(Build.SourceBranchName)-$(GitVersion.SemVer)

trigger:
  - master
  - develop

stages:
- stage: DEV
  displayName: 'DEV'
  condition: and(always(), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'develop'))
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  variables:
    contentVersion: $(GitVersion.AssemblySemVer)
    parameters.semVer.value: $(GitVersion.AssemblySemVer)
    parameters.resourceGroupName.value: 'rgName-DEV'
  jobs:
    - job: DevResourceGroup
      steps:
      - task: GitVersion@5
        inputs:
          preferBundledVersion: false
          updateAssemblyInfo: true
          configFilePath: './GitVersion.yml'
      - script: echo %Action%%BuildVersion%
        displayName: 'Set Build Number to Semantic Version'
        env:
          Action: '##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]'
          BuildVersion: '$(GitVersion.SemVer)'
      - task: FileTransform@2
        inputs:
          folderPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          xmlTransformationRules: 
          jsonTargetFiles: './ResourceGroup/resourceGroup.parameters.json'
      - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
        inputs:
          deploymentScope: 'Subscription'
          azureResourceManagerConnection: 'ConnectionName'
          subscriptionId: 'GUID'
          location: 'East US'
          templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
          csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ResourceGroup/resourceGroup.json'
          csmParametersFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ResourceGroup/resourceGroup.parameters.json'
          deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: 'develop'
          publishLocation: 'Container'

- stage: PROD
  displayName: 'PROD'
  condition: and(always(), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'master'))
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  variables:
    contentVersion: $(GitVersion.AssemblySemVer)
    parameters.semVer.value: $(GitVersion.AssemblySemVer)
  jobs:
    - job: ProdResourceGroup
      steps:
      - task: GitVersion@5
        inputs:
          preferBundledVersion: false
          updateAssemblyInfo: true
          configFilePath: './GitVersion.yml'
      - script: echo %Action%%BuildVersion%
        displayName: 'Set Build Number to Semantic Version'
        env:
          Action: '##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]'
          BuildVersion: '$(GitVersion.SemVer)'
      - task: FileTransform@2
        inputs:
          folderPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          xmlTransformationRules: 
          jsonTargetFiles: './ResourceGroup/resourceGroup.parameters.json'
      - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
        inputs:
          deploymentScope: 'Subscription'
          azureResourceManagerConnection: 'ConnectionName'
          subscriptionId: 'GUID'
          location: 'East US'
          templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
          csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ResourceGroup/resourceGroup.json'
          csmParametersFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ResourceGroup/resourceGroup.parameters.json'
          deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: 'master'
          publishLocation: 'Container'
```

So, I take the version I want, write it to the JSON file and that will be available in my release pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

After tested on my test project. I found `$($GITVERSION_MAJORMINORPATCH)` cannot get the version value, and `$env:Version` cannot be refer to variable Version. I made below changes to your build yml file and then it worked just as expected.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $versionInfo = '$(GitVersion.MajorMinorPatch)'
      Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version;]$versionInfo")
      Write-Host($versionInfo)

- script: echo %Action%%BuildVersion%
  displayName: 'Set build version'
  env:
    Action: '##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]'
    BuildVersion: '$(Version)'
```

In the powershell task I used `$(GitVersion.MajorMinorPatch)` to reference to the gitversion. And used `$(Version)` to get the version string for **BuildVersion**

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't very clear, please let me know how I can improve my question.  I do not want the alpha.70 on my MajorMinorPatch string.  Yet, it is still being passed to the build number when I run my pipeline.

Comment: @BigDevJames Thanks for sharing your Gitversion.yml. I tested with your build  pipeline and gitversion.yml, and found  `'$($GITVERSION_MAJORMINORPATCH)'` cannot get the version value, and `$env:version` cannot be refer to variable `version`. I updated above answer. Please check it out.